# Is the interesting/ignored tags feature having problems?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I thought adding an interesting/ignored tag would update the question list accordingly.

Now it gives an error trying to do the update ('k' is undefined). It will remove the highlighting for questions with an interesting tag and show questions that were previously hidden due to my ignored tags.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.13, and I've already tried clearing my cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I introduced a bug when changing the way interesting/ignored highlighting works on `/tagged` pages.

A fix will go out with the next build.